# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol CheckLr referenced in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker

legitmate_relationship.dll : Basically this dll is consumed for one of the unit test project unittest_legitimate_relationship.

As soon as I build unittest_legitimate project, giving some linker errors.

---

**error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol CheckLr referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl LrTester::LrTest()**

here is function defalcation which i am going to call in my unit test project,and which is declared in  "legitmate_relationship.h " header file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

DLL_IMPORT (bool_t)
CheckLr(STD_HANDLE hPrincipal, STD_HANDLE hCollectionIn, STD_HANDLE hCollectionOut);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

---

function is defined like this in file "lrrule.cpp"

```
DLL_EXPORT (bool_t)
CheckLr(STD_HANDLE hCollectionIn, STD_HANDLE hCollectionOut, STD_HANDLE hPrincipal)
{   

}
```

In order to make use of checklr function in unittest_legitimate project, I have added the .lib file reference in addional dependence . So that the function definition should be available for project.

If I am compiling unittest-legitimate project, I am getting linker errors as mentioned above.

call made  to checklr() in lrtest.cpp :

```
CheckLr((STD_HANDLE)permissionCollectionIn, (STD_HANDLE)permissionCollectionOut, (STD_HANDLE)principal);
```

I am not sure how to resolve such kind of linker errors.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are lrtest.cpp and legitmate_relationship.h and lrrule.cpp in the same object or not?

Comment: legitmate_relationship.h and lrrule.cpp are in legitimaterelasionship.dll files. header file has import declarations,and source file has export defnitions.

Comment: lrtest.cpp is part of unittest_legitimate-relationship.exe  project file. in this file i am making call that exported defnition.

Answer (score 0):

1.Three things to check, the legitimaterelasionship.dll project and unittest_legitimate-relationship.exe project should be the same:

MT/MD

x86/x64

cplusplus/c

2.The legitimaterelasionship.dll project generates a legitimaterelasionship.lib file. The unittest_legitimate-relationship.exe project should link to this legitimaterelasionship.lib file.

Comment: both runs for X64 and runtime library property has been set to /MDd

Comment: do you have this function "private: bool LrTester::LrTest()"?

Comment: Is the body of LrTest in cpp file and the cpp file is compiled and linked to ?

Comment: I am not sure, how to check that step.

Comment: first, where is LrTest() ? in a .h file, or in a .cpp file?

Comment: it is declared and defined in source file itself.

Comment: class LrTester : public CppUnit::TestFixture 
{ private : bool_t lrtest(); }
 this is how that method declared and defined in lrtrest.cpp  file itself.                                                                                                                                                                            

bool  
LrTester::LrTest ()
{
}

Comment: so that method is defined in a header file? does it have a body in a cpp file?